# How to run a shell script out of a simple CGI python server?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a very simple CGI python server on linux with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  ## This line enables CGI error reporting

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
handler.cgi_directories = ["/"]

httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

In the same directory, I have a script named example-bash.sh. What I want to do is simply be able to display the output of that bash script in the browser when I navigate to localhost:8000/example-bash.sh. When I try, it just opens the file instead of running it.

example-bash simply has the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ''
echo 'CGI Bash Example'
```

How can I make it run instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the shell script is executable.

```
chmod +x example-bash.sh
```

[DEMO](http://asciinema.org/a/14350)

Comment: Didn't work for me through firefox. It probably worked for you because you're already in the cmd line.

Comment: @user2997154, It works for me in browser, too (chrome, firefox).

Comment: I downloaded chrome and it worked in there, thanks. Still doesn't work in firefox though. Not sure why